# How to add [today's date +1 day]

Tags: php, wordpress, date, future

I'm currently using this code in wordpress:

```
// [date]  
function displaydate(){  
return date('l, F jS, Y');  
}  
add_shortcode('date', 'displaydate');  
// end date
```

--

What I want to do is add another shortcode that would display todays date +1day.

So I could write something like this:

'...offer runs out [todays date +1day]'

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: using javascript or jquery or ..... ????

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure tbh, whatever goes into theme functions.php in wordpress editor.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in PHP would be using the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

As for your code you would add:

```
return date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Based on your original code a 'shortcode' called 'tomorrow' would look like this:

```
// [tomorrow]  
function displaydate_tomorrow(){  
    return date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime('+1 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow', 'displaydate_tomorrow'); 
// end tomorrows date
```

Comment: Hey,

Would you mind giving me the full code so I can copy and paste it into wordpress functions editor?

I've played around with the code but I don't know how to add a shortcode so I can 'call' it later when I'm editing one of my wordpress pages/posts.

Comment: You would add the above below the existing code you posted. The new shortcode would be called 'tomorrow', as specified as the first argument in the add_shortcode function.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP documentation is really comprehensive when it comes to date manipulation, so finding a suitable solution should be quite easy. Here's one possible solution:

```
function displaydate($plus_days) {
  return date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime('+' . $plus_days . ' day'));
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Thanks for that.

I added that in but it says I can't do that because I've already declared 'displaydate' previously.

How do I get around this? And do I add in the shortcode for it?

Answer (score 0):

This was the only direct answer to this question that I could find and I thank you very much for supplying the answer.

I also played with the variables as I wanted to show an accurate date and by changing day to hours and entering -5 to GMT time as I'm in Toronto area, it worked beautifully!

For newbies, the full code that I am using is as follows:

```
 function displaydate(){
     return date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime('-5 hours')); 

 }
 add_shortcode('date', 'displaydate');
```

Then, I enter the following on the page where I wish the date to appear on my wordpress pages as:

```
Last update of this page: [date]
```

and the result is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I used this snippet to count simple estimated delivery date. It's based on dianovich snippet but his(her) snippet returns error. This works fine:

```
function displaydate( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'day'   => '0'     
    ), $atts );
    $plus_days = $atts['day'];
    return date_i18n('j F Y', strtotime('+' . $plus_days . ' day'));
}
add_shortcode('delivery_date', 'displaydate');
```

Shortcode to show:
[delivery_date day="5"]